# 3D triangulation using HALCON

Tags: camera-calibration, triangulation, stereo-3d, halcon

My aim is to calibrate a pair of cameras and use them for simple measurement purposes. For this purpose, I have already calibrated them using HALCON and have all the necessary intrinsic and extrinsic camera Parameters. The next step for me is to basically measure known lengths to verify my calibration accuracies. So far I have been using the method [intersect_lines_of_sight](https://www.mvtec.com/doc/halcon/12/en/intersect_lines_of_sight.html) to achieve this. This has given me unfavourable results as the lengths are off by a couple of centimeters. Is there any other method which basically triangulates and gives me the 3D coordinates of a Point in HALCON? Or is there any leads as to how this can be done? Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Kindly let me know in case this post Needs to be updated with code samples

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In HALCON there is also the operator `reconstruct_points_stereo` with which you can reconstruct 3D points given the row and column coordinates of a corresponding pixel. For this you will need to generate a StereoModel from your calibration data that is then used in the operator `reconstruct_points_stereo`.

In you HALCON installation there is an standard HDevelop example that shows the use of this operator. The example is called reconstruct_points_stereo.hdev and can be found in the example browser of HDevelop.

Comment: To summarize in case someone searches for this in the future, both the methods, reconstruct_points_stereo and intersect_lines_of_sight return the 3D triangulated points in HALCON. The issue was in my end where I found out that I was measuring certain points in areas where I had not placed the checkerboard during calibration, which is why i was getting large measurement errors